# Laravel model observer events doesn't work on collection method calling

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have an observer for my Product model to run some customized commands when the model is deleted. But when I use the delete function on a collection of the model my observer doesn't work.

Comment: Would be better if you could post your code here where you delete the model.

Comment: more information please!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you delete them, the observer won't be fired because the model has not been fetched before.

[Delete section of Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#deleting-models)

For example, this can fire an observer:

```
$products = App\Product::all();
$products->each->delete();
```

N.B: Of course, it's just an example, don't use it unless you want to purge your table.